# Failed to connect with PostgreSQL from PowerBI Desktop

Tags: postgresql, powerbi-desktop

I've installed the followings

1. PowerBI desktop
2. PostgreSQL
3. Npgsql v4.1.1 (from https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql/releases)
4. Visual Studio 2019 (community)

Even after installing all the above, still I am getting

> This connector requires one or more additional components to be installed before it can be used.

Is there anything else, I've to install?

Answer (score 0):

I've re-installed the Visual Studio 2019 and it works.